Solving the Stacked Integral $\int_1^{\int_1^{\int_1^{\int_1^{\dots}}2xdx}2xdx}2xdx$
A friend sent me the integral:$$\int_1^{\int_1^{\int_1^{\int_1^{\dots}}2xdx}2xdx}2xdx$$
I tried my best with the formatting, but if it's not clear, it is the integral of $2x$  with a lower bound of $1$ and the upper bound is the integral of $2x$ with a lower bound of $1$, upper bound of the integral etc.
I want to note that there is no purpose of this integral other than my own enjoyment. Here was my attempt, but I've never tried an integral like this before so I'd love to hear other techniques or learn where I went wrong.
$$\text{let }I=\int_1^{\int_1^{\int_1^{\dots}}2xdx}2xdx$$
$$I=\int_1^I2xdx$$
$$=\left.x^2\right\rvert_1^I$$
$$I=I^2-1$$
$$I^2-I-1=0$$
$$I=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$I=\phi,1-\phi$$
I found $\phi$ and its conjugate to be solutions. I'm not sure how it is possible to have two distinct solutions to the same definite integral. I also tried using limits but didn't get too far.

Of course you need a definition of this stacked integral.  You use what is (supposedly) a property of it.  But that property should be proved from the definition.

Let
$$
I_1(x) = \int_1^x 2t\;dt,
\\
I_2(x) = I_1(I_1(x)) ,
\\
\vdots
\\
I_{n+1}(x) = I_1(I_{n}(x)) .
$$
Define the symbol in the title to mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n(x)$.

The limit depends on $x$.
If $x>\phi$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n(x)= +\infty$.
If $x=\phi$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n(x)= \phi$.
If $x=1-\phi$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n(x)= 1-\phi$.
If $-\frac12 < x < \frac12$, then $I_n(x)$ has two limit points, $0$ and $-1$.
For many other values of $x$, $I_n(x)$ has two limit points, $0$ and $-1$.

Thanks for the correction.  Fixed.

There aren't two answers. $1-\phi <1,$ so $$\int_1^{1-\phi}2xdx = -\int_{1-\phi}^1 2xdx.$$ You can confirm that $1-\phi$ is not a valid solution.
